# How to use different methods to make a converter?

Tags: c#, project

I have a problem with my homework for my C# class. I need to use different methods to convert inches to feet, yards and miles.

I have come up with some code and it allows me to input inches but does not output anything different from my input. I am new to coding so this has been very frustrating.

```
using System;
namespace Lesson4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[]args)
        {
            Console.Write("Please input inches:");
            string inches = Console.ReadLine();
            double feet = ConvertInchesToFeet(int.Parse(inches));
            double yard = ConvertInchesToYards(int.Parse(inches));
            double miles = ConvertInchesToMiles(int.Parse(inches));
            Console.WriteLine(inches);
        }
        public static double ConvertInchesToFeet(int inches)
        {
            return inches* 12;
        }
        public static double ConvertInchesToYards(int yards)
        {
            return yards* 36;
        }
        public static double ConvertInchesToMiles(int miles)
        {
            return miles * 63360;
        }
    }
}
```

I am seeking to learn and any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: that is because you are only writing this: Console.WriteLine(inches); You have yards, miles in a different variable but you are not printing them anywhere. there is also another problem with your code. you are parse feet, yards to an integer but saving them to a double which is of no use. either parse them to double or save them to an int variable.

Comment: BTW your inches to feet conversion is the wrong way around - it'll give 1 inch==12 feet.

Comment: In fact, convert X to Y methods usually take the X as the argument, but two of your methods are the wrong way around, e.g. `ConvertInchesToMiles(int miles)` - that's converting miles to inches.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stackoverflow.

The problem there is that you never assign any new value to `inches` but you assign your methods' result to `feet`, `yard`, `miles`.

Try to output those variables:

...

```
Console.WriteLine(inches);

Console.WriteLine("In feet: " + feet.ToString());
Console.WriteLine("In yard : " + yard .ToString());
Console.WriteLine("In miles : " + miles .ToString());
```

Comment: That did seem to work. Thank you very much. The other part of this problem is that I have to have the output placed with two spots after the decimal. How do I do that?